# JS HTMLElement.click() removes the URL part after the #

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I have a Vue 3 app using Vue Router 4.

I have a button using the javascript HTMLElement.click() method to click on a hidden file input.

When I click it and the browser's file picker pops up, all the part of my URL after the hash gets cut out which changes my view.

I have no errors whatsoever so I really don't know what is causing this. Any idea ?

Comment: We have no code, whatsoever so we really don't know what is causing this. Most likely your button is within a form, and clicking it submits the form.

Comment: Thanks @Teemu for the sarcastic comment ! But what you said helped me somehow. The element I was clicking is a Bootstrap dropdown item which is a link with href="#". This was causing my URLs to change. Thanks

Comment: Despite of the slight sarcasm, the comment was meant to be helpful. If you've a debugging question, always attach the related code to the question too.